# strange python 2.7 dict behavior: key not inside while clearly there

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, import, keyerror

I have written a Parser that takes a JSON configuration and creates objects from it. I first create a well known object, and try to dynamically import a module (which may be from a user), while loading its class via the defined `creator` method of that module.

Here is some testing code:

```
import json
import imp
import os.path as path
from lib.config.members import Member
from lib.tasks.task import Task


class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._loadedMods = {"tasks": {}}

    def _load_module(self, clazz, modPart):
        """
        imports and caches a module.

        :param clazz: the filename of the module (i.e email, ping...)
        :param modPart: the folder of the module. (i.e services, parsers...)
        :return: the imported/cached module, or throws an error if it couldn't find it
        """
        mods = self._loadedMods[modPart]
        if clazz in mods:
            return mods["class"]
        else:
            #mod = __import__(clazz)

            p = path.join("lib", modPart, clazz + ".py")
            mod = imp.load_source(clazz, p)
            mods[clazz] = mod
            return mod

    def replace_with_import(self, objList, modPart, items_func, class_check):
        """
        replaces configuration dicts with their objects by importing and creating it in the first step.
        In the second step the original list of json config dicts gets replaced by the loaded objects

        :param objList: the list of objects which is iterated on
        :param modPart: the folder from the module (i.e tasks, parsers)
        :param items_func: function to get a pointer on the list of json-config-objects to replace. Takes one argument and
        should return a list of
        :param class_check: currently unsupported
        """
        for obj in objList:
            repl = []
            items = items_func(obj)
            for clazzItem in items:
                try:

                    clazz = clazzItem["class"]
                    mod = self._load_module(clazz, modPart)
                    item = mod.create(clazzItem)
                    if class_check(item):
                        repl.append(item)
                    else:
                        print " ignoring class " + clazzItem["class"] + "! It does not pass the class check!"

                except ImportError, err:
                    print "could not import " + clazz + ": " + str(clazzItem) + "! reason:"
                    print str(err)
                except KeyError, k:
                    print "Key " + str(k) + " not in classItem " + str(clazzItem)
                except Exception, e:
                    print "Error while replacing class ( " + clazz + " :" + str(e) + ")"

            del items[:]
            items.extend(repl)

    def _create_raw_Object(self, jsonDict, msgName, creator):
        """
        creates an Main object from the configuration, but just parses raw data and hands it to the object

        :param jsonDict: the configuration file part as dict
        :param msgName: name of object for error message
        :param creator: function pointer which is taking two arguments: identifier of the object and arguments.
        :should return an object
        :return: a list of objects returned by creator
        """
        items = []
        for key, val in jsonDict.items():
            try:
                item = creator(key, val)
                items.append(item)
            except Exception, e:
                print "ignoring " + msgName + ": " + key + "! reason:"
                print str(e)
        return items

jsonFile = '''
{
    "members":{
        "homer":{
            "name": "Homer Simpson",
            "comment": "Security Inspector",
            "tasks": [{"class":"email", "type": "donut", "args": {"rcpt": "homer_j_simpson@burnscorp.sp"}},
            {"class":"email", "type": "do", "args": {"rcpt": "my_other_mail@burnscorp.sp"}}]
        }
    }
}
'''

jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFile)

parser = Parser()

creator = lambda name, values: Member(name, **values)
members = parser._create_raw_Object(jsonDict["members"], "Members", creator)

items_func = lambda member: member.get_tasks()
class_check = lambda task: isinstance(task, Task)
parser.replace_with_import(members, "tasks", items_func, class_check)

for d in members:
    print d.__dict__
```

As you can see, a Member can have a list of arbitary tasks, and which one it should import is defined in its `class` attribute, but as soon as two of them has the same value for the class (which shouldn't break json the way we define it) I get a strange `KeyError` :

```
Key 'class' not in classItem {u'args': {u'rcpt': u'my_other_mail@burnscorp.sp'}, u'type': u'do', u'class': u'email'}
```

Why do I get this strange error? Any hint that my give me a clue whats going on is very welcome, as I feel hopeless, debugging this for hours.

I think that Member and Email/Task class are unrelated but Ill post them for completeness:

lib/config/members.py

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, id, name="",  comment="", tasks=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.tasks = []
        self.add_task(tasks)
        self.comment = comment

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def add_task(self, task):
        if task is None:
            return
        if isinstance(task, list):
            self.tasks.extend(task)
        else:
            self.tasks.append(task)

    def get_tasks(self):
        return self.tasks
```

lib/tasks/[task|email].py

```
class Task:
    """
    Base class for all built-in Tasks.
    """

    def set_task_type(self, taskType):
        """
        sets the type of this task.

        Be aware! this method can only get called once!

        :param taskType: the type of this task
        """
        if hasattr(self, "_taskType"):
            raise Exception("taskType is only allowed to set once!")
        self.taskType = taskType  

    def get_task_type(self):
        """
        :return: the type set by set_type_task
        """
        return self._taskType

"""
The email task.
"""

from lib.tasks.task import Task


class EmailTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.set_task_type(kwargs["type"])
        self.recipient = kwargs["args"]["rcpt"]

    def execute_task(self, msg):
        pass

def create(taskDict):
    return EmailTask(**taskDict)
```

Comment: Try converting the key to `unicode` : `key = key.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I would try printing out the original exception, instead of your own `print`. Just to be sure you aren't receiving a different exception than you think.

Comment: @Wessie, you brought the enlightement!! it was the method `_load_module` which was throwing at `if clazz in mods:
            return mods["class"]` :) post this as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are eating the actual exception by replacing it with your own custom `print` in `replace_with_import`. As I noted in the comment section.

You generally want to keep you `try` blocks small and very predictable, knowing exactly what can be raised and what you should handle at that point in the code. The less complexity in your `try` block the better.